# Wordpress function.php Error

Tags: php, wordpress, syntax

ive been working on my wordpress website source code, when I try to reload the page I get this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /home3/snesni/public_html/wp-content/themes/Activello-master/functions.php 
>   on line 284

My `function.php` line 284-285 says:

```
endif; // activello_woo_setup  add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'activello_woo_setup' );
```

And I cant seem to change WP theme. Not sure what to do.

Below is the `function.php`.

```
<?php
/**
 * activello functions and definitions
 *
 * @package activello
 */

/**
 * Set the content width based on the theme's design and stylesheet.
 */
if ( ! isset( $content_width ) ) {
    $content_width = 1090; /* pixels */
}

/**
 * Set the content width for full width pages with no sidebar.
 */
function activello_content_width() {
  if ( is_page_template( 'page-fullwidth.php' ) ) {
    global $content_width;
    $content_width = 1008; /* pixels */
  }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'activello_content_width' );

if ( ! function_exists( 'activello_main_content_bootstrap_classes' ) ) :
/**
 * Add Bootstrap classes to the main-content-area wrapper.
 */
function activello_main_content_bootstrap_classes() {
    if ( is_page_template( 'page-fullwidth.php' ) ) {
        return 'col-sm-12 col-md-12';
    }
    return 'col-sm-12 col-md-8';
}
endif; // activello_main_content_bootstrap_classes

if ( ! function_exists( 'activello_setup' ) ) :
/**
 * Sets up theme defaults and registers support for various WordPress features.
 *
 * Note that this function is hooked into the after_setup_theme hook, which
 * runs before the init hook. The init hook is too late for some features, such
 * as indicating support for post thumbnails.
 */
function activello_setup() {

  /*
   * Make theme available for translation.
   * Translations can be filed in the /languages/ directory.
   */
  load_theme_textdomain( 'activello', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );

  // Add default posts and comments RSS feed links to head.
  add_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' );

  /**
   * Enable support for Post Thumbnails on posts and pages.
   *
   * @link http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_theme_support#Post_Thumbnails
   */
  add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );

  add_image_size( 'activello-featured', 1170, 550, true );
  add_image_size( 'activello-slider', 1920, 550, true );
  add_image_size( 'activello-thumbnail', 330, 220, true );
  add_image_size( 'activello-medium', 640, 480, true );

  // This theme uses wp_nav_menu() in one location.
  register_nav_menus( array(
    'primary'      => esc_html__( 'Primary Menu', 'activello' )
  ) );

  // Enable support for Post Formats.
  add_theme_support( 'post-formats', array(
        'video',
        'audio',
    ) );

  // Setup the WordPress core custom background feature.
  add_theme_support( 'custom-background', apply_filters( 'activello_custom_background_args', array(
    'default-color' => 'FFFFFF',
    'default-image' => '',
  ) ) );

  // Enable support for HTML5 markup.
  add_theme_support( 'html5', array(
    'comment-list',
    'search-form',
    'comment-form',
    'gallery',
    'caption',
  ) );

  /*
   * Let WordPress manage the document title.
   * By adding theme support, we declare that this theme does not use a
   * hard-coded <title> tag in the document head, and expect WordPress to
   * provide it for us.
   */
  add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );

}
endif; // activello_setup
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'activello_setup' );

/**
 * Register widgetized area and update sidebar with default widgets.
 */
function activello_widgets_init() {
  register_sidebar( array(
    'name'          => esc_html__( 'Sidebar', 'activello' ),
    'id'            => 'sidebar-1',
    'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget'  => '</aside>',
    'before_title'  => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title'   => '</h3>',
  ));

  register_widget( 'activello_social_widget' );
  register_widget( 'activello_recent_posts' );
  register_widget( 'activello_categories' );
  register_widget( 'activello_instagram_widget' );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'activello_widgets_init' );


/* --------------------------------------------------------------
       Theme Widgets
-------------------------------------------------------------- */
require_once(get_template_directory() . '/inc/widgets/widget-categories.php');
require_once(get_template_directory() . '/inc/widgets/widget-social.php');
require_once(get_template_directory() . '/inc/widgets/widget-recent-posts.php');
require_once(get_template_directory() . '/inc/widgets/widget-instagram.php');

/**
 * This function removes inline styles set by WordPress gallery.
 */
function activello_remove_gallery_css( $css ) {
  return preg_replace( "#<style type='text/css'>(.*?)</style>#s", '', $css );
}

add_filter( 'gallery_style', 'activello_remove_gallery_css' );

/**
 * Enqueue scripts and styles.
 */
function activello_scripts() {

  // Add Bootstrap default CSS
  wp_enqueue_style( 'activello-bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/css/bootstrap.min.css' );

  // Add Font Awesome stylesheet
  wp_enqueue_style( 'activello-icons', get_template_directory_uri().'/inc/css/font-awesome.min.css' );

  // Add Google Fonts
  wp_enqueue_style( 'activello-fonts', '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,400italic,700,700italic|Montserrat:400,700|Maven+Pro:400,700');

  // Add slider CSS only if is front page ans slider is enabled
  if( ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) && get_theme_mod('activello_featured_hide') == 1 ) {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'flexslider-css', get_template_directory_uri().'/inc/css/flexslider.css' );
  }

  // Add main theme stylesheet
  wp_enqueue_style( 'activello-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );

  // Add Modernizr for better HTML5 and CSS3 support
  wp_enqueue_script('activello-modernizr', get_template_directory_uri().'/inc/js/modernizr.min.js', array('jquery') );

  // Add Bootstrap default JS
  wp_enqueue_script('activello-bootstrapjs', get_template_directory_uri().'/inc/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery') );

  // Add slider JS only if is front page ans slider is enabled
  if( ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) && get_theme_mod('activello_featured_hide') == 1 ) {
    wp_register_script( 'flexslider-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/js/flexslider.min.js', array('jquery'), '20140222', true );
  }

  // Main theme related functions
  wp_enqueue_script( 'activello-functions', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/js/functions.min.js', array('jquery') );

  // This one is for accessibility
  wp_enqueue_script( 'activello-skip-link-focus-fix', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/js/skip-link-focus-fix.js', array(), '20140222', true );

  // Add instafeed/instagram
  if( is_active_widget( false, false, 'activello-instagram', true ) ){
    wp_enqueue_script('activello-instafeedjs', get_template_directory_uri().'/inc/js/instafeed.min.js', array('jquery') );  
  }

  // Threaded comments
  if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
  }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'activello_scripts' );

/**
 * Custom template tags for this theme.
 */
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/template-tags.php';

/**
 * Custom functions that act independently of the theme templates.
 */
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/extras.php';

/**
 * Customizer additions.
 */
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/customizer.php';

/**
 * Load Jetpack compatibility file.
 */
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/jetpack.php';

/**
 * Load custom nav walker
 */
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/navwalker.php';

/**
 * Load custom metabox
 */
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/metaboxes.php';

/**
 * Social Nav Menu
 */
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/socialnav.php';

/* Globals */
global $site_layout, $header_show;
$site_layout = array('pull-right' =>  esc_html__('Left Sidebar','activello'), 'side-right' => esc_html__('Right Sidebar','activello'), 'no-sidebar' => esc_html__('No Sidebar','activello'),'full-width' => esc_html__('Full Width', 'activello'));
$header_show = array(
                        'logo-only' => __('Logo Only', 'travelify'),
                        'logo-text' => __('Logo + Tagline', 'travelify'),
                        'title-only' => __('Title Only', 'travelify'),
                        'title-text' => __('Title + Tagline', 'travelify')
                      );

/* Get Single Post Category */
function get_single_category($post_id){

    if( !$post_id )
        return '';

    $post_categories = wp_get_post_categories( $post_id );

    if( !empty( $post_categories ) ){
        return wp_list_categories('echo=0&title_li=&show_count=0&include='.$post_categories[0]);
    }
    return '';
}

// Change what's hidden by default
add_filter('default_hidden_meta_boxes', 'be_hidden_meta_boxes', 10, 2);
function be_hidden_meta_boxes($hidden, $screen) {
    if ( 'post' == $screen->base || 'page' == $screen->base ) {
        // removed 'postexcerpt',
        $hidden = array(
            'slugdiv',
            'trackbacksdiv',
            'postcustom',
            'commentstatusdiv',
            'commentsdiv',
            'authordiv',
            'revisionsdiv'
        );
    }
    return $hidden;
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'activello_woo_setup' ) ) :
/**
 * Sets up theme defaults and registers support for various WordPress features.
 */
function activello_woo_setup() {
    /*
     * Enable support for WooCemmerce.
    */
    add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );

}
endif; // activello_woo_setup
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'activello_woo_setup' );
```

Comment: If you have a backup of your site just replace the function.php file

Comment: Any chance you were developing in windows and deploying on a Unix machine? This may be related to the difference in line endings between the two systems. http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~krueger/csc209h/tut/line-endings.html

Comment: The above file parses correctly; I'm not sure where you're getting your error from. Are you certain that's the actual file giving you the error?

Comment: Well what I did to solve this, I went to file manager-->selected web root--> then went to the wp-content-->themes--> found my theme and renamed it by adding a "2" at the end. Then I could finally login to WP Dashboard. But im not sure what gave me this error.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use regular if wrapping?

```
/**
 * Sets up theme defaults and registers support for various WordPress features.
 */
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'activello_woo_setup' );

if ( !function_exists( 'activello_woo_setup' ) ){
    function activello_woo_setup() {
      /* Enable support for WooCommerce. */
      add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
    }
}
```

Doubt it would make any difference, but you never know...

Answer (score -3):

on line 281 : `if ( ! function_exists( 'activello_woo_setup' ) ) {`

replace : `if ( !function_exists( 'activello_woo_setup' ) ) {`

Comment: I'm struggling to see what the difference you're suggesting actually is

Comment: there is a space between exclamation mark ( ! ) and function_exists

Comment: They are meant to be written togethor **!function_exists()**

Comment: No. That will make no difference at all - you can add a space between the two, and PHP will interpret it correctly.